# GNU find and masking the {} for some shells - which?

Tags: shell, find, xargs, quoting

The man page for GNU find states:

> ```
> -exec command ;
>     [...] The  string `{}'  is  replaced  by the current 
>     file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the 
>     arguments to the command, not just in arguments where 
>     it is alone, as in some  versions  of  find.
>     Both  of  these  constructions might need to be escaped 
>     (with a `\') or quoted to protect them from expansion 
>     by the shell.
> ```

That's from the man to `find` (GNU findutils) 4.4.2.

Now I tested this with bash and dash, and both don't need to have the `{}` being masked. Here is a simple test:

```
find /etc -name "hosts" -exec md5sum {} \;
```

Is there a shell, for which I really need to mask the braces? Note, that it doesn't depend upon whether the file found contains a blank (invoked from bash):

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "U*" -exec ls -d {} \; 
/home/stefan/Ubuntu One
```

This changes if the found file is passed to a subshell:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 3 -type d -name "U*" -exec bash -c 'ls -d {}' \; 
ls: cannot access /home/stefan/Ubuntu: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access One: No such file or directory
```

which can be solved by:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 3 -type d -name "U*" -exec bash -c 'ls -d "$0"' {} \;
```

in contrast to:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 3 -type d -name "U*" -exec bash -c 'ls -d "{}"' \; 
/home/stefan/Ubuntu One
```

but that's not what the man page is talking about, is it? So which shell treats `{}` in a different way?

Comment: @Volker Siegel: Your edit might have happened in good intent, but I checked my current find-manual and your corrections are wrong, You also missed the opportunity to summarize your edits which is a bad habit, So I roll your changes back. Sorry, fellow.

Comment: Oh, thank you for rolling it back if it broke something. I was remembering that the text compiler which generates the man page format used to generate these "typographical quotes" as an artifact of the rendering definition. It can also render to TeX for perfect printout formatting. I noticed the quotes because they confused the syntax highlighting.  I assumed the that the unusual first quote is wrong when used in code, and still assume that. Note that the two changes were in description text, not code. So if we see them as typography - aesthetical rendering - they are right.

Comment: Looks like in the info output rendering, the same quote is used on both sides. There is no doubt my change made it different from the original, you are right. But has it caused any problem? (I consider the first quote as a bug in the man rendering definition, it's the only case of typography as far as I know.)

Comment: I just checked: `{}' does not work on the command line. That's technically correct, but I do not like it that an unsuspecting user gets a strange error when he tries to copy and paste it.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: It is prose text, not code, so what shall a user copy-paste here? And it is a citation of the man page from 2011. I don't see any value correcting the passage to then point out, why I made corrections to the man page. The topic is complicated enough. If this was your question, I wouldn't try to convince you, to cite the man page accurately but for my question, I'm not in the mood of doing compromises. Citation is citation.

Comment: It's a citation - a  clear argument that convinces me. It is even explicitly pointed out that it is one. My change was wrong, accepted. I'll explain why I usually change these quotes when I see them. I think of the use case of a person new to using the basic shell tools. He will use `find` quite early in his/her learning process, as it is important. It is harder to understand than other tools. This very question hints to that. He will read the text, and quite possibly copies the ` `{}'` (It is part of the prose, but he may need quotes anyway, and other reasons.) ...

Comment: ...  A good reason to copy it is that he has noticed the unusual quote, and assumes at first they may be relevant. Note that the characters used to quote are different. That is common in professional print, but not in the shell (I have never seen it.) That's why I still think the quotes should be replaced elsewhere. Regarding edit comments, you are right that my change needs special attention, because the edit diff is not trivial. Thanks for convincing me for this question!

Answer (score 31):

**Summary**: If there ever was a shell that expanded `{}`, it's really old legacy stuff by now.

In the Bourne shell and in POSIX-compliant shells, braces (`{` and `}`) are ordinary characters (unlike `(` and `)` which are word delimiters like `;` and `&`, and `[` and `]` which are globbing characters). The following strings are all supposed to be printed literally:

```
$ echo { } {} {foo,bar} {1..3}
{ } {} {foo,bar} {1..3}
```

A word consisting of a single brace is a [reserved word](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_04), which is only special if it is the first word of a command.

Ksh implements brace expansion as an incompatible extension to the Bourne shell. This can be turned off with `set +B`. Bash emulates ksh in this respect. Zsh implements brace expansion as well; there it can be turned off with `set +I` or `setopt ignore_braces` or `emulate sh`. None of these shells expand `{}` in any case, even when it's a substring of a word (e.g. `foo{}bar`), due to the common use in arguments to [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) and [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xargs.html).

[Single Unix v2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_004) notes that

> In some historical systems, the curly braces are treated as control operators. To assist in future standardisation activities, portable applications should avoid using unquoted braces to represent the characters themselves. It is possible that a future version of the ISO/IEC 9945-2:1993 standard may require that `{` and `}` be treated individually as control operators, although the token `{}` will probably be a special-case exemption from this because of the often-used `find` `{}` construct.

This note was dropped in subsequent versions of the standard; the [examples for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html#tag_04_55_17) have unquoted uses of `{}`, as do the [examples for `xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xargs.html#tag_04_173_17). There may have been historical Bourne shells where `{}` had to be quoted, but they would be really old legacy systems by now.

The csh implementations I have at hand (OpenBSD 4.7, [BSD csh on Debian](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/csh), tcsh) all expand `{foo}` to `foo` but leave `{}` alone.

Comment: 2@mress:3 B$ ls -d {te,pl}*
    platform-tools/ platforms/      temp/
    2@mress:4 B$ echo $BASH_VERSION
    3.2.48(1)-release
(hm, markup doesnt work in comments)

Comment: @geekosaur: [Only a small subset of markdown works in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). I don't know what you're trying to say. If this is about ksh et al's brace expansion, read my paragraph beginning with “Ksh implements brace expansion as an incompatible extension”.

Comment: That was `bash` (see `$BASH_VERSION`).  Brace expansion is very much alive and well.

Comment: @geekosaur: Yes, but what does this have to do with `{}`? Brace expansion (in Bourne-style shells) only triggers when there is a comma or sometimes `..` between the braces, never for `{}`. Also, it is not condoned by POSIX, not even mentioned as an extension, but obviously you need to protect braces in the general case (not `{}`) since most shells out there perform it.

Comment: That *was* the point.  The `{}` syntax originated in `csh`, but `{}` expanded to the empty string.  Newer shells recognize that that's nonsensical, but there are still some old `csh`s out there.

Comment: @geekosaur: Can you say which specific csh-version on which specific platform? I would prefer to test it myself (if it is possible on linux) or be assured, that the person testet it himself.

Comment: @Gilles - Thank you for creating this answer!

Comment: @geekosaur, `{}foo` would expand to `foo`, but `{}` would expand to `{}` (except when within backticks, but quoting would not help) and was documented as such. I verified it for the csh of 2BSD (first release), 2.79BSD, 2.8BSD and 2.11BSD.

Answer (score 18):

The `{}` needed to be quoted in versions of the `fish` shell prior to 3.0.0.

```
$ fish -c 'echo find -exec {} \;'
find -exec  ;
```

And in the rc shell (also `akanga` based on `rc`, but not `es`):

```
$ rc -c "echo find -exec {} ';'"
line 1: syntax error near '{'
```

Those are probably not the shells the authors of that GNU find documentation had in mind when they wrote that text since `fish` was first released in 2005 (while that text or similar was already there in 1994) and `rc` was not originally a Unix shell.

There are some rumors of some versions of `csh` (the shell that introduced brace expansion) requiring it. But it's hard to give credit to those since the first release of `csh` in 2BSD didn't. Here as tested in a PDP11 emulator:

```
# echo find -exec {} \;
find -exec {} ;
```

And the [man page from 2BSD `csh` clearly states](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-2-Snapshot-Development/man/csh.u#L504):

> As a special case `{', `}' and `{}' are passed undisturbed.

So I would find it very strange if a subsequent version of csh or tcsh later broke that.

It could have been to work around some bugs in some versions. Still with that 2BSD csh (that's the same in 2.79BSD, 2.8BSD, 2.11BSD):

```
# csh -x
# echo foo {} bar
echo foo {} bar
foo {} bar
# echo `echo foo {} bar`
echo `echo foo {} bar`
echo foo {} bar
foo  bar
```

Quoting doesn't help though:

```
# echo `echo foo '{}' bar`
echo `echo foo '{}' bar`
echo foo {} bar
foo  bar
```

You could quote the whole command substitution:

```
# echo "`echo foo {} bar`"
echo `echo foo {} bar`
echo foo {} bar
foo {} bar
```

But that's passing one argument to that outer echo.

In `csh` or `tcsh`, you'd need to quote the `{}` when not on its own like in:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec cp {} '{}.back' \;
```

(though that kind of `find` usage is not portable as some `find`s only expand `{}` when on its own).

Answer (score 1):

In a word, `csh`.  `bash` and other modern shells recognize that the user probably isn't asking for a null brace expansion.  (Modern `csh` is actually `tcsh` and may also handle `{}` sanely by now.)

Comment: Nice to hear, but I'm asking for the opposite, a shell for which doesn't handle it sanely.

Comment: You're assuming that someone would go in and rip out the info page's reference to extra quoting just because Linux systems all have newer `csh`.  Not everyone runs GNU utilities on Linux; in fact it's quite common to install them on older commercial Unix systems whose bundled commands are limited.  (Replacing `csh` on those systems is less likely, because system scripts may rely on the idiosyncrasies of the original `csh`, and even if users were all configured to use a newer `csh`, `root` would almost certainly need to remain the bundled version.)

Comment: No. I'm in a debate with a guy who says, that in our wiki we should give the advice to use "{}" all the time, because the man page says so. And now I would like to know if there is a shell I'm not using, like ksh, zsh, tcsh, csh or XYZsh which I don't know, for which this claim is true, or whether I honestly can assume, that there isn't. If there are shells for different Unixes which need the "{}", that would be a fine explanation why the sentence is still in the man page, but not appropriate as advice for linux beginners.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if `pdksh` does the right thing... although the correct answer to *that* is probably "real `ksh` is FOSS these days".

Comment: Pdksh, like mksh, ksh93, bash and zsh, only expands braces when there's a comma in between (or `..` for ksh93, bash and zsh). Only (t)csh expands `{foo}` to `foo`, and even it leaves `{}` alone (at least on recent BSD's).