# How can I use two bash commands in -exec of find command?

Tags: bash, find

Is it possible to use 2 commands in the `-exec` part of `find` command ?

I've tried something like:

```
find . -name "*" -exec  chgrp -v new_group {}  ; chmod -v 770 {}  \;
```

and I get:

> find: missing argument to -exec
>   chmod: cannot access {}: No such file or directory
>   chmod: cannot access ;: No such file or directory

Comment: Note that `-name "*"` matches every name, so it's a no-op test that can be removed. Also, both `chmod` and `chgrp` has a `-R` option for recursive operation.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As for the `find` command, you can also just add more `-exec` commands in a row:

```
find . -name "*" -exec chgrp -v new_group '{}' \; -exec chmod -v 770 '{}' \;
```

Note that this command is, in its result, equivalent of using

> chgrp -v new_group file **&&** chmod -v 770 file

on each file.

All the `find`'s parameters such as `-name`, `-exec`, `-size` and so on, are actually **tests**: `find` will continue to run them one by one as long as the entire chain so far has evaluated to *true*. So each consecutive `-exec` command is executed **only if** the previous ones returned *true* (i.e. `0` exit status of the commands). But `find` also understands logic operators such as *or* (`-o`) and *not* (`!`). Therefore, to use a chain of `-exec` tests **regardless** of the previous results, one would need to use something like this:

```
find . -name "*" \( -exec chgrp -v new_group {} \; -o -true \) -exec chmod -v 770 {} \;
```

Comment: +1: Yes, that's the most elegant way to do it. If you can explain, why you use`'{}'` (apostrophes around the braces), please visit: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8647/4485

Comment: @user Unfortunately, I don't know if it is still necessary. I did some test just now and haven't come across a situation where it would change anything. I guess it's just "good practice" that will die out.

Comment: The quotes are important for files with spaces in their names.

Comment: @naught101 No, the quotes may be needed in some non-standard shells, such as `fish` and `csh`, but are definitely not needed in POSIX-like shells (`sh`, `dash`, `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, `yash`).

Answer (score 20):

```
find . -name "*" -exec sh -c 'chgrp -v new_group "$0" ; chmod -v 770 "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: @Gilles: The wonders of `-c`'s odd handling of $0 make me think this is wrong every time I glance at it, but its definitely correct.

Comment: I like the explicit shell being defined...

Comment: This answer (and Giles's answer) seems like the better answer for the question given the `sh -c`.

Comment: Instead of passing the argument in as `$0`, pass `sh` as the first argument and then reference `$1`, i.e. `find -exec sh -c 'chgrp...' sh {} \;`     The value of `$0` is used e.g. as the command name when printing error messages from the shell.

Comment: @Angel, what does this answer do that's different from the advice in the linked answer?

Answer (score 16):

Your command is first parsed by the shell into two commands separated by a `;`, which is equivalent to a newline:

```
find . -name "*" -exec chgrp -v new_group {}
chmod -v 770 {} \;
```

If you want to run a shell command, invoke a shell explicitly with `bash -c` (or `sh -c` if you don't care that the shell is specifically bash):

```
find . -name "*" -exec sh -c 'chgrp -v new_group "$0"; chmod -v 770 "$0"' {} \;
```

Note the use of `{}` as an argument to the shell; it's the zeroth argument (which is normally the name of the shell or script, but this doesn't matter here), hence referenced as `"$0"`.

You can pass multiple file names to the shell at a time and make the shell iterate through them, it'll be faster. Here I pass `_` as the script name and the following arguments are file names, which `for x` (a shortcut for `for x in "$@"`) iterates over.

```
find . -name "*" -exec sh -c 'for x; do chgrp -v new_group "$x"; chmod -v 770 "$x"; done' _ {} +
```

Note that since bash 4, or in zsh, you don't need find at all here. In bash, run `shopt -s globstar` (put it in your `~/.bashrc`) to activate `**/` standing for a recursive directory glob. (In zsh, this is active all the time.) Then

```
chgrp -v new_group -- **/*; chmod -v 770 -- **/*
```

or if you want the files to be iterated on in order

```
for x in **/*; do
  chgrp -v new_group -- "$x"
  chmod -v 770 -- "$x"
done
```

One difference with the `find` command is that the shell ignores dot files (files whose name begins with a `.`). To include them, in bash, first set `GLOBIGNORE=.:..`; in zsh, use `**/*(D)` as the glob pattern.

Comment: This answer (and Glenn's answer) seems like the better answer for the question given the `sh -c`.

Comment: Both `chgrp` and `chmod` has a `-R` option for recursive operation.