# Where have I set my bash PATH?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path

I want to remove `~/bin` from my PATH.  I set it up months ago when Linux (Ubuntu) was very new to me, but I don't know how I added it...

Nothing shows up when I search all the files listed below.
Where else could it be being set?  It is being pre-pended after `$HOME/.profile` prefixes PATH with `$HOME/bin`

If it makes any difference, I get the same PATH from both the command-prompt and a running script.

```
#!/bin/bash
{
  echo "first dir of PATH is: '${PATH%%:*}'"
  shopt -s nullglob
  cat \
    /etc/profile \
    /etc/bash.bashrc \
    /etc/profile.d/*.sh \
    $HOME/.bashrc \
    $HOME/.bash_aliases \
    /etc/bash_completion \
    $HOME/.bash_completion* \
    $HOME/.profile \
    $HOME/.profile_zap \
    $HOME/.bash_profile* \
    $HOME/.bash_login* \
  | sed -rne '/~\/bin/p'
}
```

Output is:

```
first dir of PATH is: '~/bin'
```

Comment: Try grepping for `PATH` instead.  If still no luck, check all files for anything that is being sourced.

Comment: Did you check your ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile for it?
If not have a look at the /etc/profile. I think you'll find it in one of these places.

Comment: Thanks everyone... all suggestions have been helpful... it was in `~/.gnomerc`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to trace the full environment load on login. Just an idea.

Since /etc/profile is the first file sourced, you can add to it at the very top a:

```
set -x
exec 2> /tmp/debug.log
```

Then open *a new* terminal and do a `bash -l`; after that go to the original terminal and remove the lines added (you want to have a working environment, don't you?).

You should end with a full trace of all the steps of the loading_the_bash_environment at /tmp/debug.log. It will be a loooong file.

With that you must be able to locate where the "~/bin" gets into your PATH

I'd look first for a grep of all the files sourced. From your post I bet that the ~/bin in the path is set in a different file of those you've listed.

Comment: @hmontoliu.. I've had a couple of problems with this.. First, nothing is going to the log, but I am getting a lot of output in the terminal (`konsole`) ... The first reference to `~/bin` shows it already in the path, but I can see no hint of where it came from.. It is, at this point, already followed by the `$HOME/bin` from `$HOME/.profile` (I'm sure it's from there, as I've used a special extra directory for this test) .... Howerver, I've managed to find it empirically, by searching all my text files.. It comes from `~/.gnomerc`.. and I need to re-log in to cause it to change. ??!! ..

Comment: Are you sure that you've pasted the lines on top of /etc/profile and that you're executing it with a plain `bash -l`? It must send the debugging (-x) which goes to stderr to /tmp/debug.log; indeed I've just tested this and works as I've expected

Comment: I'll try it again (again)... This log analysis is definitely *the way* to go (when all else fails :) and this is a good opportunity for me to get a better understand of it...

Comment: ... I'll have to put this log issue into the too hard basket for now..  It still didn't output to the logfile, but I got hundreds of lines in the terminal.. but that's okay.. It has been a good intro to the debug log.. and I've certainly got a much better feel of the config files... thanks...

Comment: I had to replace `set` with `exec` in the second line, then it worked perfectly for me :)