# Rename files with random characters from sha1sum. Will the names be unique?

Tags: files, rename, hashsum

I'm using this command to rename files with random characters from `sha1sum` and move all files from subdirectories to the current directory:

```
for fname in `find . -type f`; do mv "$fname" $(echo "$fname" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d' ').html; done
```

1. But the question is: Does it create unique filenames? I'm worried the generated
   name from sha1sum may not be unique (generated twice or more).
2. If I run the above command, and then run another one in another directory, will
   it generate a unique file name for each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sha1sum` outputs will be unique as long as inputs are unique.
(Unless you are very extremely unlucky and you found some `sha1sum` collision).

As for your use case: It's a good habit to use `printf '%s' "$fname"` instead of `echo "$fname"`, the former will work when `$fname` is `-n`, or `-e`,… See also [enzotib remark](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18993/rename-files-with-random-characters-from-sha1sum-does-it-unique/18996#18996), I missed that at first glance.

Also, I'm not sure exactly what are your motivations, but you may consider feeding `sha1sum` with file contents instead of filenames. This way, you would obtain a unique filename for each unique content.

Comment: Note that using the sha1 of file contents would give more unique results but would also take far more time (depending on the size of files of course).

Comment: If you hash the content, you'll end up with the same filename if the contents are the same. That may or may not be desirable (it isn't if you later want to modify one of the files).

Answer (score 2):

First, a few shell matters:

- Don't use `` for fname in `find …` `` as this will mangle file names and will fail (because the command line is too long) if there are too many files with too long names. Use `find -exec` instead. Since you need shell expansion in the command executed by `find`, [invoke a shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18077/how-can-i-use-two-bash-commands-in-exec-of-find-command/18080#18080).
- You need double quotes around command substitutions as well as variable substitutions (`"$fname"`, `"$(echo …)"`).
- `echo` mangles backslashes on a few shells (it also mangles a few arguments beginning with `-`, but that's not an issue here since all arguments will begin with `./`). A way to print any string literally is `printf "%s\n" "$fname"`, or `printf "%s"` "$fname" to avoid a final newline. Here I see no reason to take the hash of the filename plus a final newline as opposed to the hash of the filename.

So we get this command:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(printf "%s" "$0" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d" ").html' {} \;
```

It will be slightly faster to invoke a shell for a whole batch of names at once.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for fname; do mv "$fname" "$(printf "%s" "$fname" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d" ").html; done' _ {} +
```

A problem with this method is that if `mv` starts to act before `find` has finished traversing the directory, files that have been moved may be picked up by `mv`. This is not an issue with your command because it waits for `find` to finish before starting moving files. So put the renamed files in a different directory hierarchy. This will solve another problem which your proposed command also has, which is that `mv` may overwrite an existing file that happens to be called `<sha1sum>.html`.

```
mkdir ../staging
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for fname; do mv "$fname" ../staging/"$(printf "%s" "$fname" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d" ").html; done' _ {} +
find . -depth \! -name "." -type d -exec rmdir {} +
mv ../staging/* .
```

Now on to your main question: two files with different paths will map to two different SHA-1 hashes. Mathematically speaking, there exist distinct strings with identical SHA-1 hashes (that's obvious since there are infinitely many strings but only finitely many hashes). However, practically speaking, no one knows how to find them: there is no known collision for SHA-1. It is possible that one day in the future SHA-1 will be broken, in which case your procedure will be safe only against accidental collisions, not against malicious attackers. If that happens (not any time soon), you should upgrade to whatever is considered a secure hash algorithm at the time.

As for your second question: the hash is fully determined by the string you hash. So if you have two files called `tweedledum/staple` and `tweedledee/staple` and you run that renaming procedure from each directory `tweedledee` and `tweedledum` in turn, then both directories will end up with a file called `1c0ee9c1eed005a476403c7651b739ae5bc7cf2a.html`. If you want to have different names, you need to put some distinguishing content in the hashed text, such as the name of the directory.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest to substitute

```
for fname in `find . -type f`; do
```

with

```
find . -type f | while read -r fname; do
```

Next, regarding sha1sum, it should be "virtually" unique, meaning that the probability to have to different files with the same checksum if considerably low, so that you can safely assume it is unique.