# Bash: How to read one line at a time from output of a command?

Tags: bash, shell, find, pipe

I am trying to read the output of a command in bash using a `while loop`.

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done <<< $(find . -type f)
```

The output I got

```
ranveer@ranveer:~/tmp$ bash test.sh
./test.py ./test1.py ./out1 ./test.sh ./out ./out2 ./hello
ranveer@ranveer:~/tmp$
```

After this I tried

```
$(find . -type f) | 
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

but it generated an error `test.sh: line 5: ./test.py: Permission denied`.

So, how do I read it line by line because I think currently it is slurping the entire line at once.

Required output:

```
./test.py
./test1.py
./out1
./test.sh
./out
./out2
./hello
```

Comment: I suggest reading [Bash FAQ 01](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - lots of useful info and advice about traps to avoid.

Comment: For the `while read` part, see [Understanding IFS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs) and the questions linked there.

Comment: For using `find`, see [How can I use two bash commands in -exec of find command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18077/how-can-i-use-two-bash-commands-in-exec-of-find-command) or [Executing user defined function in a find -exec call](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50692/executing-user-defined-function-in-a-find-exec-call) (which this question is mostly a duplicate of).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

There's a mistake, you need `< <(command)` not `<<<$(command)`

`< <( )` is a [Process Substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), `$()` is a [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) and `<<<` is a *here-string*.

Answer (score 22):

There's no need for command substitution if you want to use pipe. `read` reads from `stdin` by default, so you just pipe into it:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
while read -r -d '' line
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

or in one line

```
find . -type f -print0 | while read -r -d '' line; do echo "$line"; done
```

Using `-print0` and `-d ''` is a protective measure against potential newline character in filenames, which by default indicates end of line to `read` (this can be changed with `-d`). `''` used above is effectively null byte in `bash` (equivalent to `$'\0'`).

Another already mentioned approach is to use `find`'s `-exec` option. Most likely that would be the best option performance-wise (remember to use `-exec cmd {} +` variant so that it won't fork a process for each line being processed). But it really depends on what you do inside the `while` loop and how much data you process. The difference might be negligible or acceptable for your case.

Answer (score 16):

Note that there's nothing stopping file names from containing newline characters. The canonical way to run a command for each file *found* by find is.

```
find . -type f -exec cmd {} \;
```

And if you want things done in bash:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    something with "$file"
  done' bash {} +
```

Also, the canonical way to call the "read" command in scripts (if you don't want it to do extra processing on the input) is:

```
IFS= read -r var
```

`-r` is to stop `read` from treating backslash characters specially (as an escape character for separators and newline), And IFS= to set the list of separators to the empty string for `read` (otherwise if any whitespace character was in that list, they would be stripped from the beginning and end of the input).

Using loops in shells is usually a bad idea (not how things are done in shells where you make several tools work collectively and concurrently to a task rather than running one or more tools hundreds of times in sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that invoking commands has a cost (irrespective of what they do). This can have very negative impact on performance if you put them into a loop that will have multiple iterations. In case you need to process the output in some way, consider using `awk`. It is very powerful and can quickly handle a lot of input:

```
find . -type f | awk '{print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A small modification of [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52031/31363).

```bash
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo $0; head $0;' {} \;
```

This shows how the script you give to `bash -c` takes the first argument.