# processing command output line by line, without mixing standard input

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdin

So, I have a problem very similar to [Bash: How to read one line at a time from output of a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52026/bash-how-to-read-one-line-at-a-time-from-output-of-a-command), I am doing:

```
while read path; do mplayer $path; done < <(find-me-random-mp3s)
```

or

```
find-me-random-mp3s | while read path; do mplayer $path; done
```

The command `find-me-random-mp3s` outputs file paths each on a new line. The problem starts when `mplayer` runs, it starts consuming lines from `find-me-random-mp3s` output, i.e. lines that were supposed to be filled inside the `path` variable on each iteration.

I went on with this dirty fix:

```
find-me-random-mp3s | while read path; do cat /dev/null | mplayer $path; done
```

But I don't really like it, it blocks my terminal interaction with mplayer too.

Is there any alternative method that I can use in such case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
exec 3<&0
while read line
do
    mplayer "$line" <&3
done < <(find-me-random-mp3s)
```

This copies terminal input to file descriptor 3.  In the while loop, stdin is everywhere read from your `find-me-random-mp3s` program except for the `mplayer` line which gets its stdin from file descriptor 3 which is your terminal.  Hence, you can still interact with `mplayer`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a different file descriptor:

```
exec 3< <(find-me-random-mp3s)
while IFS= read -r -u3 path; do mplayer "$path"; done
exec 3<&-
```

Answer (score 3):

A simpler variation of [@glenn-jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman)'s solution that should work too, I think:

```
while read -u3 path; do mplayer "$path"; done 3< <(find-me-random-mp3s)
```