# While loops not looping through all values

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have created a few pieces of code - in python and C – that have to be run multiple times, each run with a new set of input values. To do so, I have created a Unix shell script which should run the various programs for the number of different inputs:

```
#!/bin/sh
_file="${1:-/dev/null}"

while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4  
do
    cd folder1
    cd folder2
    echo "$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 " > inputs.txt
    mpiexec -n 4 a_C_code
    cd ..
    cd ..
    python3 python_code_1.py
    python python_code_2.py
    python python_code_3.py
    python python_code_4.py
    echo "$f1" #So I know how many times the loops has been performed

done < "$_file"
```

The file that is being read into the script has the following form:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
...
```

However, when I execute the program, it only loops through the first set of inputs (in this example, 1 2 3 4) and finishes without running the programs for the various other sets of inputs.

Comment: Perhaps one of the commands inside the loop is consuming standard input? see for examle [processing command output line by line, without mixing standard input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107727/processing-command-output-line-by-line-without-mixing-standard-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell code looks OK, and a simplified text version works as expected:

```
seq 12 | paste - - - - | 
while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 ; do 
    echo "$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 " 
done
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   4    
5   6   7   8    
9   10  11  12
```

Therefore [*steeldriver*'s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510974/while-loops-not-looping-through-all-values#comment944728_510974) is probably correct, and either the `mpiexec` or one of the `python` programs are consuming the remaining lines of input so that `echo`  never gets to the second line of input.

As an example, consider the above code with one more hungry set of commands added:

```
seq 12 | paste - - - - | 
while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 ; do 
     echo "$f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 "
     (read x; read x; read x;) 
done
```

Output (note the missing lines):

```
1   2   3   4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It turns out that mpiexec is consuming the remainder of the inputs.