# Flattening a nested directory

Tags: files, directory, rename, recursive

This is probably very simple, but I can't figure it out. I have a directory structure like this (`dir2` is inside `dir1`):

```
/dir1
    /dir2 
       |
        --- file1
       |
        --- file2
```

What is the best way to 'flatten' this directory structure in such a way as to get `file1` and `file2` into `dir1` not `dir2`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/633945/how-can-i-merge-multiple-directories-into-one

Comment: Thanks @Ferroao copying that [solution from askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633945/how-can-i-merge-multiple-directories-into-one) here `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I file mv --backup=numbered file .` I also follow with [another command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371393/85530)  `rename 's/((?:\..+)?)\.~(\d+)~$/_$2$1/' *.~*~`  to keep the numbering of duplicated files before the extension.

Answer (score 126):

You can do this with GNU `find` and GNU `mv`:

```
find /dir1 -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -t /dir1 -i '{}' +
```

Basically, the way that works if that `find` goes through the entire directory tree and for each file (`-type f`) that is not in the top-level directory (`-mindepth 2`), it runs a `mv` to move it to the directory you want (`-exec mv … +`). The `-t` argument to `mv` lets you specify the destination directory first, which is needed because the `+` form of `-exec` puts all the source locations at the end of the command. The `-i` makes `mv` ask before overwriting any duplicates; you can substitute `-f` to overwrite them without asking (or `-n` to not ask or overwrite).

As Stephane Chazelas points out, the above only works with GNU tools (which are standard on Linux, but not most other systems). The following is somewhat slower (because it invokes `mv` multiple times) but much more universal:

```
find /dir1 -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -i '{}' /dir1 ';'
```

POSIXly, passing more than one argument, but using `sh` to reorder the list of arguments for `mv` so the target directory comes last:

```
LC_ALL=C find /dir1 -path '/dir1/*/*' -type f -exec sh -c '
  exec mv "$@" /dir1' sh {} +
```

Comment: Edited to use `-exec +` so that it doesn't execute a large number of processes of `mv`

Comment: @Random832 And going to revert again, because + doesn't work. `mv` needs the destination as the final argument, but + would have the sources as the final argument. Find wont even *accept* the syntax you changed it to (`find: missing argument to \`-exec'`)

Comment: @Random832 but I suppose `mv` has a `-t` we can use, so I'll change it to that.

Comment: @Random832 See [How can I use two bash commands in -exec of find command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18077/how-can-i-use-two-bash-commands-in-exec-of-find-command/18080#18080)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Thanks for the edit. I've added back in the non-GNU variant.

Comment: Does this technique work with hidden files? also does the depth need to be relative to root, or the directory in which the find command is called?

Comment: @Dom `find` prints hidden (dot) files by default. The depth is relative to the directory you pass to find.

Comment: most useful!!!!

Comment: Or `find ./dir -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -f '{}' ./dir ';'` if overriding duplicates

Comment: @Atav32 thank you, edited in your suggestion in https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/52816/8

Comment: Nice answer! What does the '{}' stands for?

Comment: @a--m `{}` is replaced by find with the file name/path.

Comment: in macOs `mv` doesn't support `-t`, so Atav32's solution is one of the few ones that works!

Comment: how to do it with cp instead of mv?

Comment: @NadavB I think GNU (at least) `cp` takes the same `-t` argument.

Answer (score 65):

In zsh:

```
mv dir1/*/**/*(.D) dir1
```

`**/` traverses subdirectories recursively. The [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `.` matches regular files only, and `D` ensures that dot files are included (by default, files whose name starts with a `.` are excluded from wildcard matches). To clean up now-empty directories afterwards, run `rmdir dir1/**/*(/Dod)` — `/` restricts to directories, and `od` orders the matches depth first so as to remove `dir1/dir2/dir3` before `dir1/dir2`.

If the total length of the file names is very large, you may run into a limitation on the command line length. Zsh has builtins for `mv` and `rmdir` which are not affected by this limitation: run `zmodload zsh/files` to enable them.

With only POSIX tools:

```
find dir1 -type f -exec mv {} dir1 \;
find dir1 -depth -exec rmdir {} \;
```

or (faster because it doesn't have to run a separate process for each file)

```
find dir1 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" dir1' _ {} +
find dir1 -depth -exec rmdir {} +
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Especially with the concise zsh version.

Comment: The zsh option also works in bash if you have `shopt -s globstar` in your `.bashrc`. So you can just `mv ./**/*.* ./` and then `rm -r <directories>`.

Comment: @JollyLlama No, that doesn't do the same thing. `**/*(.D)` in zsh only matches regular files. There's no equivalent in bash. `**/*.*` matches directories as well. And for whatever reason you excluded files with no `.` in their name, which you delete rather than move.

Comment: You’re right, I didn’t realize I was making the (false) assumption that we were dealing with user files and folders, so I assumed that files will all be of the form `file.ext` and folders will all be extensionless. What I did works if those assumptions hold, but not in general.

Answer (score 10):

tar and zip both have the ability to incorporate and then strip away a directory structure, so I was able to quickly flatten a nested directory with

`tar -cvf all.tar *`

followed by moving all.tar to a new location then

`tar -xvf all.tar --strip=4`

Comment: This is a good point, and one I hadn't thought of. You could even just do this with a pair of tar's connected by a pipe. Something like (haven't tried it) tar -c * | tar -x --strip 4

Comment: Too much overhead

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on the popular answer for this question, since I had a use-case for flattening a directory containing files of the same name.

```bsh
dir1/
├── dir2
│   └── file
└── dir3
    └── file
```

In this case, the `-i` (`--interactive`) option passed to `mv` wouldn't yield the desired result to flatten the directory structure and handle name conflicts. So it's simply replaced with `--backup=t` (equivalent to `--backup=numbered`). More documentation on the `-b` (`--backup`) option available at https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Backup-options.

Resulting in:

```bsh
find dir1/ -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -t dir1/ --backup=t '{}' +
```

Which yields:

```bsh
dir1/
├── dir2
├── dir3
├── file
└── file.~1~
```

Comment: is there anyway to make `file~1~.extension`, otherwise got `file.extension.~1~` when duplicated, so had to rename that manually to be able to preview

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this :

```
cp /dir1/dir2/file{1,2} /another/place
```

or for each files matching `file[0-9]*` in the subdir :

```
cp /dir1/dir2/file[0-9]* /another/place
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: I should have indicated this, but I have to many files to use `{}` in my real problem.

Comment: See my second solution

Comment: Bingo. Thanks for the help. This is definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

Staying in dir1 you can just do it with `mv dir2/* .`. If you have more subfolders on dir2 level you can use `mv */* .`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote two functions you can use together that do just that, you can limit the directory level by adding a `-maxdepth $VAL` parameter.

```
# This scripts flattens the file directory
# Run this script with a folder as parameter:
# $ path/to/script path/to/folder

#!/bin/bash

rmEmptyDirs(){
    local DIR="$1"
    for dir in "$DIR"/*/
    do
        [ -d "${dir}" ] || continue # if not a directory, skip
        dir=${dir%*/}
        if [ "$(ls -A "$dir")" ]; then
            rmEmptyDirs "$dir"
        else
            rmdir "$dir"
        fi
    done
    if [ "$(ls -A "$DIR")" ]; then
        rmEmptyDirs "$DIR"
    fi
}

flattenDir(){
    local DIR="$1"
    find "$DIR" -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -i '{}' "$DIR" ';'
}

read -p "Do you wish to flatten folder: ${1}? " -n 1 -r
echo    # (optional) move to a new line
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    flattenDir "$1" &
    rmEmptyDirs "$1" &
    echo "Done";
fi
```

Comment: Man, I just misused your script by forgetting the path argument, that just really fucked up my server.
Ok, I'm the guy who copy paste things and misuse them, but guys, be wise and add checks / confirmations on scripts that delete / move stuffs like that...

Comment: Whoops! I am sorry to hear that. Hope you have a backup... I added a confirmation for future protection.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno that's much better this way. My server is still running flawlessly, i commented the "flatten" part to just delete empty directories recursively from (and that was my error) root, until I saw an error that made me stop running the script.