# Unnest directories that have same name

Tags: directory

I have too many files being in directories with same name EXAMPLE:

```
~/foo/bar/foo/bar/1.flac
~/foo/bar/foo/bar/bar/foo/foo/0.flac
```

I want to have

```
~/foo/bar/0.flac
~/foo/bar/1.flac
```

Comment: downvote more, what do you wanna accomplish?

Comment: The question is really ambiguous, do you want ~/foo/bar/FILE all the time? How should the script know when to move files or when to leave them alone? You aren't helping people answer your question, you're saying "do this for me".

Comment: @alexhairyman yes.The script should know to move FILE up to /foo/bar whatever foo and bar is.

Comment: -1 for me too. "I haz no code for u" without more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a nested directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52814/flattening-a-nested-directory)

Comment: @user83873, I have voted to close it as duplicate of [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52814/flattening-a-nested-directory) question. Check that question and I tried Gille's solution with zsh. I believe it is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all the files have different names you can do:

```
cd ~/foo/bar
find foo -type f -name "*.flac" -exec mv -t . {} \;
```

(you can leave out the `-name "*.flac"` part).