# mv: add number to file name if the target exists

Tags: rename, mv

I'm moving a file to a different folder and would like to add some kind of index to the newly moved file if a file with the same name exists already (the old one should remain untouched). For example, if `file.pdf` existed I would prefer something like `file1.pdf` or `file_1.pdf` for the next file with the same name.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/267255/mv-rename-if-exists) I've found a variant for the opposite idea — but I don't want to make a "backup".

Does `mv` have some parameters out of the box for that scenario? I use Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: That is exactly what the solution in your linked question's answer does. Have you tried it?

Comment: It gave me something like this: `file.pdf` and `file.pdf.~1~` - I don't know what to think of it

Comment: `file.pdf` already existed in the destination directory.  `file.pdf.~1~` is the first file moved that _would have_ klobbered `file.pdf` if it had not been renamed.

Comment: Doesn't it actually add the suffix to the *original*?

Comment: I'd prefer something like `file1.pdf` or `file_1.pdf`

Answer (score 14):

As the answer to the question you linked already states, `mv` can suffix files that would otherwise get overwritten by the file you move with a number to give them a unique file name:

```
mv --backup=t <source_file> <dest_file>
```

The command works by appending the next unused number suffix to the file that was first in the destination directory. The file you are moving will keep its original name.

However, this will appends suffixes like `.~1~`, which seems to be not what you want:

```
$ ls
file.pdf
file.pdf.~1~
file.pdf.~2~
```

You can rename those files in a second step though to get the names in a format like `file_1.pdf` instead of `file.pdf.~1~`, e.g. like this:

```
rename 's/((?:\..+)?)\.~(\d+)~$/_$2$1/' *.~*~
```

This takes all files that end with the unwanted backup suffix (by matching with the shell glob `*.~*~`) and lets the `rename` tool try to match the regular expression `((?:\..+)?)\.~(\d+)~$` on the file name. If this matches, it will capture the index from the `.~1~`-like suffix as second group (`$2`) and optionally, if the file name has an extension before that suffix like `.pdf`, that will be captured by the first group (`$1`). Then it replaces the complete matched file name part with `_$2$1`, inserting the captured values instead of the placeholders though.

Basically it will rename e.g. `file.pdf.~1~` to `file_1.pdf` and `something.~42~` to `something_42`, but it can not detect whether a file has multiple extensions, so e.g. `archive.tar.gz.~5~` would become `archive.tar_5.gz`

Comment: *"Files that were originally present in the destination folder do not get modified in any way"* - sure about that? try `echo 'This is foo' > foo ; echo 'This is bar' > bar ; mv --backup=t foo bar ; cat bar` (it's the original `bar` that becomes `bar.~1~`)

Comment: @steeldriver Oops, you're right. That's quite counter-intuitive behaviour in my opinion though. Editing...

Comment: Yeah I don't know the history of why it was done that way

Comment: also `--backup=numbered` can be used instead of `--backup=t`

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue that a BASH script was encountering / overwriting same-named files during a `mv` operation.

The `mv --backup=t <src> <dest>` solution here, and https://serverfault.com/questions/267255/mv-rename-if-exists works well. However I also wanted to preserve the file extension.

Here is a solution.

```bash
[victoria@victoria out]$ ls -l

total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 apple1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 apple2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 apple3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 apple4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 apple5.txt

[victoria@victoria out]$ for f in *; do mv -f --backup=t "$f" banana.txt; done

[victoria@victoria out]$ ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana.txt.~1~
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana.txt.~2~
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana.txt.~3~
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana.txt.~4~

[victoria@victoria out]$ for f in *; do mv 2>/dev/null -v "$f" "`echo $f | sed -r 's/(.*)\.(.*)\.~([0-9]{1,})~$/\1_\3.\2/'`"; done

renamed 'banana.txt.~1~' -> 'banana_1.txt'
renamed 'banana.txt.~2~' -> 'banana_2.txt'
renamed 'banana.txt.~3~' -> 'banana_3.txt'
renamed 'banana.txt.~4~' -> 'banana_4.txt'

[victoria@victoria out]$ ls -l

total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana_1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana_2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana_3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana_4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 6 May 23 18:13 banana.txt

[victoria@victoria out]$
```

**Explanation:**

- Using a `sed` regex command I capture the three parts of the source filename,

`/(.*)\.(.*)\.~([0-9]{1,})~$/`

i.e., in sequence match:

- everything: `(.*)  # captured as group \1`
- period `\.`
- everything: `(.*)  # captured as group \2`
- period `\.`
- tilde: `~`
- any number of numbers: `([0-9]{1,})  # captured as group \3`
- the second tilde and end of line: `~$`

and rearrange them:

`/\1_\3.\2/`   # note the placement of the period, not necessary to -escape here`

Note the use of backticks `` ` `` at the start/end of the `"`-quoted `echo` command.

`2>/dev/null` ignores any spurious warnings, if they occur.

Leave out the `-v` flag if you don't want verbose output from the `mv` command.

---

See also:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

  https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

  for additional explanations, examples of the regex syntax, and regex capture groups and backreferences
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643041/how-do-i-rename-files-found-with-the-find-command

  for the use of the `find` command to rename files

Answer (score 0):

Ok, don't judge me by my not poor bash-skills but this solution worked for me. (I appreciated [Byte Commanders solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371393/115043) yet it's due to its restrictions not what I was looking for)

So here's my small script that does the job...

- `$2` is the path
- `$3` the filename
- `$punktpdf` is just ".pdf"

So here's my little script...

```
if [ -s $2$3$punktpdf ]; then
    for i in `seq 1 100000`;
        do
            if [ ! -s $2$3$i$punktpdf ]; then
                if mv scan.pdf $2$3$i$punktpdf; then                        
                    echo $3$i$punktpdf
                    exit 0
                    break
               else                        
                    echo 1
                    break
               fi
           fi
        done
    else
        #Regular mv
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
outputFile="/videos/test/test.mp4"
version=0
preservedOutputFile="${outputFile%.*}-prev-v$version.mp4"
while [ -f "$preservedOutputFile" ]
do
    echo "$preservedOutputFile exist!"
    version=$((version+1))
    preservedOutputFile="${outputFile%.*}-prev-v$version.mp4"
done

if [ $version -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Preservering existing \"$outputFile\" by renaming it to \"$preservedOutputFile\"!"
    #rename file
    mv "$outputFile" "$preservedOutputFile"
else
    echo "$outputFile doesn't exist! No need to preserve!"
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

I created `move` command.
`move` command add index if file exists.

```
npm i -g @gauravnumber/move
```

### Example

Folder Structure

```
.
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
├── 3.txt
├── 4.txt
├── 5.txt
└── 6.txt
```

Type below command.

```
move 1.txt 2.txt
```

`2.txt` file already exists. `move` command append index on the file. After running above command. Folder structure looks like this.

```
.
├── 2_1.txt
├── 2.txt
├── 3.txt
├── 4.txt
├── 5.txt
└── 6.txt
```

`move` command also support multiple files.

```
move *.jpg dirname
```

```
move *.png *.jpg dirname
```

```
move dirname1 dirname2
```

```
move dirname1/* dirname2
```

Here is link to [repo](https://github.com/gauravnumber/move.js)

Comment: (1) Please describe how to *use* the software. (2) If you wrote this software, you must say so *in the answer.*