# How do I write a shell script to flatten directories?

Tags: shell-script, files, find, directory, recursive

I wrote a simple script to delete useless files from a directory using the `find` command.

Now I'm wondering if I can add lines to the script to flatten directories, but not *completely* flattened.

e.g.,
If I have a big directory named `cleantarget`:

- cleantarget

  - Folder A

    - Folder A1
    - Folder A2
  - Folder B

    - Folder B1

      - Folder B11

I want the end result to be:

- cleantarget

  - Folder A
  - Folder B

I do NOT want the result to be:

- cleantarget

  - all my files

There are 16000 files in this directory, so it'd be nice to do this with a script, so I can run it occasionally when the directory gets messed up again.

How do I do this?

EDIT: In essence, this means: I want a script, that will separately flatten each sub-directory within a given target directory. i.e., flatten Folder A, flatten Folder B, and flatten Folder C, and so on until all directories within `cleanfolder` are flattened.

Comment: What determines if a file should be deleted?

Comment: Do you mean flatten all of the directories under 'Folder A' and 'Folder B'. As in move all of the files from the subdirectories in A and B to A and B and then delete the subdirectories in A and B?

Comment: Did you check to see whether [this had been asked before](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+flatten+directory&atb=v142-1&ia=web)?

Comment: So do you want to flatten `directory A`, and `flatten directory B` etc.?

Comment: @Giraffer, yes that is exactly what I mean. I want the script to flatten all subfolders within a target folder.

Comment: @Jesse_b, don't worry about that part. My script currently does it already.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes I have checked. Everyone else wants to flatten one folder. I want to flatten all subfolders within a target folder. There can be hundreds of these subfolders.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, yes, and then Directory C, etc. until all subfolders within cleantarget is flattened.

Comment: @johnnywatts: If you are already getting the files where is the issue?  Do you just need to know how to use `rm`?

Comment: @johnnywatts So, take any of those solutions and apply them to to each folder individually? Doesn't sound more complicated than adding a `for`-loop around a piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines should work:

```
find "/path/to/cleantarget" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read line; do
    find "${line}" -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -t "${line}" -i '{}' +
    rm -r "${line}"/*/
done
```

This will flatten Folder A and Folder B, asking if you want to overwrite duplicates, and remove the folders afterwards.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52816/284212

Comment: Hello, I don't think that will work.

That only scans two folders and flattens them. It doesn't proceed with other folders.

Comment: @johnnywatts Sorry, I didn't see your update. I only thought there were two folders.

Comment: It should work now.

Comment: My apologies, but it didn't work. I get the error "find: paths must precede expression: 'rm'"

Comment: This works...with errors. If there are two files with the same name, it will ask to overwrite, but the file will be already deleted by the time you get the prompt.

Comment: I'd recommend replacing the first `find ... | while read` loop with a simple `for line in "/path/to/cleantarget"/*/; do`. One possible downside: it won't flatten invisible subdirectories (unless you set `shopt -s dotglob` first).