# Recursively flattening subdirectories in a root directory and maintaining level 1 sub-directory structure

Tags: files, directory, recursive

I have a large n-level directory structured as follows:

```
root
  |
   subdir1
      |
       sub_subdir1
           |
            ....(n-2 levels).....
                                 |
                                  file1
  |
   subdir2
      |
       sub_subdir2
           |
            ....(n-2 levels).....
                                 |
                                  file2
```

I want to flatten the directory so that all level 1 **subdirs** contain **files**. I also want to remove the level 2 to (n-1) **sub_subdirs** as they contain no files. Please note that the subdirs all have different names.

**Desired Result**

```
root
  |
   subdir1
      |
       file1
  |
   subdir2
      |
       file2
```

I have found a lot of posts explaining methods to *flatten* directories but none that explains how to do this in a controlled manner, i.e.,

- by specifying the levels to be flattened
- or doing it recursively for all sub_directories in a root directory

Comment: Did you find any solutions to flatten a directory structure, moving all the files to the *top* level and keeping no subdirectories? If so, just apply that solution in each top-level subdirectory.

Comment: True. This can be done. However, I am just looking for a more functional solution. Thanks tho !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using zsh:

```
cd /root
for subdir in subdir*
do
  mv "$subdir"/**/*(.) "$subdir"
  rm -r "$subdir"/*(/)
done
```

This:

1. changes to the "/root" directory (from your example)
2. loops over every subdirectory named `subdir*` (again from your example: matching subdir1 and subdir1)
3. moves the (expected one, but would match all) matching file(s) under that subdirectory into that subdirectory. This uses zsh's `**` recursive globbing feature, limited then by the glob qualifier `*(.)` which says: any entry in this directory that's a plain file
4. after moving the file, recursively remove every subdirectory under that subdirectory; this again uses a zsh glob qualifier `*(/)` which says to match entries that are directories.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry, my question does not clarify this. The subdirs in my actual structure have names and the names are all different. So name matching won't work. How can I work around that? Thanks!

Comment: Then, from the root directory, simply select everything: `for subdir in */`

Comment: why do I have error for the line of mv: syntax error near unexpected token '('

Comment: @BrianHong are you using zsh?

Answer (score 1):

In bash, do the following:

```bsh
shopt -s dotglob
for d in root/*/
do
        find "$d" -type f -exec mv -i -t "$d" {} +
        find "$d" -mindepth 1 -type d -delete
done
```

This looks at everything in “`root`”, including dot-files. 
If you don’t need to look at dot-files, leave out the `shopt -s dotglob`. 
Warning: do not add **`.*`** or `root/.*`
to the `for` command.

The `/` at the end of the glob (`root/*/`),
as suggested by Jeff, gets us only the subdirectories,
so we don’t need to test each one (e.g., with `if`).

For every *subdirectory* of `root`,
find all files in and under that subdirectory
and move them into the subdirectory. 
Use `-i` to prevent overwriting files
(e.g., if you have multiple files called `file1`
distributed under `subdir1`). 
`-i` means “interactive”,
and it will ask you whether it should overwrite an existing file. 
Be aware that it *might* refuse to do so, even if you say “yes”. 
If your version of `mv` doesn’t support the `-t` option,
replace the line with the `mv` command with

```bsh
        find "$d" -type f -exec mv -i {} "$d" ';'
```

Then delete all the subdirectories under the top-level subdir. 
Note that this (`find` … `-delete`) will fail if any files didn’t get moved.

This is partially inspired by [derobert’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52814/23408#52816)
to [Flattening a nested directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52814/23408).

Comment: Thanks! Since I am on a mac, the target-directory flag -t is not allowed. Would you know a workaround?

Comment: (1) I updated my answer.  (Does the system notify you of that?)  (2) If you wanted a zsh answer, it would have been nice if you had said so in the question.

Comment: Thanks. No, I do not have a requirement as such. Both answers are good. Wish I could green check both.