# bash - can I do : find .... -exec this && that?

Tags: bash, find

Is there a way to logically combine two shell commands that are invoked with **find - exec**?

For instance to print out all the **.csv** files that contain the string foo together with its occurrence I would like to do:

```
find . -iname \*.csv -exec grep foo {} && echo {} \;
```

but **bash** complains with "missing argument to '-exec' "

Comment: You could use 2 `-exec` in sequence or use a single `-exec sh -c 'grep foo "$0" && printf %s\\n "$0"' {} \;`.

Comment: This has tripped me up repeatedly: I always expect that the first argument passed to `sh` (in this case `{}`) will be `$1` and `$0` will be something like `sh`. But in fact, you are correct, the first argument shows up as `$0`. Having the first argument be the name of the invoking command is just a convention, that isn't automatically enforced in these cases.

Comment: Maybe should be merged with this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18077/4801

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`-exec` is a predicate that runs a command (not a shell) and evaluates to *true* or *false* based on the outcome of the command (zero or non-zero exit status).

So:

```
find . -iname '*.csv' -exec grep foo {} \; -print
```

would *print* the file path if `grep` finds foo in the file. Instead of `-print` you can use another `-exec` predicate or any other predicate

```
find . -iname '*.csv' -exec grep foo {} \; -exec echo {} \;
```

See also the `!` and `-o` find operators for negation and *or*.

Alternatively, you can start a shell as:

```
find . -iname '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
   grep foo "$1" && echo "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Or to avoid having to start a shell for every file:

```
find . -iname '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    grep foo "$file" && echo "$file"
  done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem you're facing is that the shell first parses the command line, and sees two simple commands separated by the `&&` operator: `find . -iname \*.csv -exec grep foo {}`, and `echo {} \;`. Quoting `&&` (`find . -iname \*.csv -exec grep foo {} '&&' echo {} \;`) bypasses that, but now the command executed by `find` is something like `grep` with the arguments `foo`, `wibble.csv`, `&&`, `echo` and `wibble.csv`. You need to instruct `find` to run a shell that will interpret the `&&` operator:

```
find . -iname \*.csv -exec sh -c 'grep foo "$0" && echo "$0"' {} \;
```

Note that the first argument after `sh -c SOMECOMMAND` is `$0`, not `$1`.

You can save the startup time of a shell process for every file by grouping the command invocations with `-exec … +`. For ease of processing, pass some dummy value as `$0` so that `"$@"` enumerates the file names.

```
find . -iname \*.csv -exec sh -c 'for x in "$@"; do grep foo "$x" && echo "$x"; done' \ {} +
```

If the shell command is just two programs separated by `&&`, `find` can do the job by itself: write two consecutive `-exec` actions, and the second one will only be executed if the first one exits with the status 0.

```
find . -iname \*.csv -exec grep foo {} \; -exec echo {} \;
```

(I assume that `grep` and `echo` are just for illustration purpose, as `-exec echo` can be replaced by `-print` and the resulting output is not particularly useful anyway.)

Comment: I tend to avoid using "$0" for that, as it's also used by the shell to display error messages. For instance, you could see a confusing `./some-file: grep: command not found` error message. `-exec find sh -c '... "$1"' sh {} \;` wouldn't have the issue. There's a typo (related) in your second find command.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case I would do:

`find . -iname \*.csv -exec grep -l foo \{\} \;`

Or if you have [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/):

`ack -al -G '.*\.csv' foo`

To answer your actual question, something like this may work:

`find . -iname \*.csv -exec sh -c "grep foo {} && echo {}" \;`

Comment: That latter find command is not-only non-portable but also very dangerous as file paths end up being evaluated as shell code.

Comment: All the more reason to try and avoid it by using ack/grep properly :)

Comment: jw013's alternative (given in a comment to the question) is safer in this respect. (Just noticed that Gilles' and Stephane's answers use the same technique.)