# missing argument to find -exec

Tags: bash, arch-linux, find

I want to remove certain files using find and -exec. But unlikely bash tells me, that I'm "missing" some argument.

```
find . -name *.png -exec rm {} /;
```

what do I miss?

same "missing argument" return for my attempt to rename some files:

```
find . -name ic_launcher.png -exec mv {} other_name.png /;
```

Can somebody tell me, what bash does miss, and why this command isn't successful?

Comment: Are you really putting `/;` at the end? If so, try `\;` instead.

Comment: By the way `find` has `-delete` option. There is no need in `-exec rm {} \;`.

Comment: @D_Bye yeah, it works. If you could explain WHY I have to take a backslash instead of a slash I'll accept this

Comment: @rush never mentioned `-delete`. But this wouldn't work for my `mv`

Comment: Backslash and slash are not the same thing at all.  Backslashes lean backwards: `\\ `, Forward slashes, or just slashes, lean forwards: `/`.  In Unix, slashes are generally path separators, while backslashes are generally used for quoting / escaping.

Comment: @jw013 shure, but then I could not understand, why the manual from `find` (and I guess its usually used under unix) suggests the `slash` or `path-separator` `/` to quote out the `;` instead of the `backslash` \

Comment: @jw013 sorry about that! I was actually misreading it, most likely because I found so many examples that use the slash instead of the backslash. In fact the manpage is right!

Comment: Wherever you found those examples that used the wrong slash must not be a very good resource.  I would recommend not going there for examples anymore.

Comment: Rafael T: If you refer to MS-DOS and Windows, which use backslashes instead of slashes, please note, that UNIX is the older one, so if somebody is using something `instead`, it is the other way round.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The semicolon at the end needs to be quoted or escaped so that it is passed to `find` instead of being interpreted by the shell.

```
find . -name ic_launcher.png -exec mv '{}' other_name.png ';'
```

or

```
find . -name ic_launcher.png -exec mv '{}' other_name.png \;
```

should do what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's because the shell might want to expand `{}` and interpret `;` as a command separator.

Comment: It's almost never necessary to quote `{}`.  There was actually an entire question about that, but I can't find it because the site can't search for `{}`.  The issue is the `/;` typo in the original question.

Comment: Found it: [modern shells don't require quoting `{}`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8647/9537).

Comment: @jw013 That is a very fair point. I guess I usually tend to go for something that will definitely work. And after having experienced issues with no quoting, I usually quote the braces. Possibly a bit too much for my own good.

Comment: Yup, no harm in over-quoting.  It's definitely better to err that way than the other way, but leaving out redundant quotes does save some keystrokes :).  Normally I don't point out redundant quotes but in this case I just wanted to make sure the questioner understood where the real issue was, i.e. the misquoted `;` character.

Answer (score -4):

use Pipe like the example below:

find . -name 'spam-*' | xargs rm

Comment: that is a workaround to do what I which, but no answer on what I miss. I will use your solution for now, but I'd still like to know what I miss on the find command

Comment: Are you quoting the * wildcard?
`find . -name "*.png"` will find all png files in or below the current dir, without those double quotes the _shell_ will expand the * so you'll find all png files with the same name as one in the current dir - probably not what you meant.

Comment: If you use xargs in combination with find, use -print0 etc. to sanitize against blanks etc. in filenames, so in general it is much more easy to use -exec instead, or, for `rm`, just `-delete`.

Comment: While this may help to do what the OP is trying to do, it does not at all answer the question that was asked.