# How do I perform an action on all files with a specific extension in subfolders in an elegant way?

Tags: bash, shell, find

My current best bet is:

```
for i in $(find . -name *.jpg); do echo $i; done
```

Problem: does not handle spaces in filenames.

Note: I would also love a graphical way of doing this, such as the "tree" command.

Comment: Can't you simply put quotes around `$i`? I do that and it works fine. Is there something wrong with that approach?

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/22142)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The canonical way is to do

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec echo {} \;
```

(replace `\;` with `+` to pass more than one file to `echo` at a time)

or (GNU specific, though some BSDs now have it as well):

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -r0 echo
```

zsh:

```sh
for i (**/*.jpg(D)) echo $i
```

Comment: If you are using **xargs -0**, you should match it with **find -0**

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, no quoting {} makes no difference. {} is expanded by find, not the shell. An improvement would be not to use `echo` which expands escape sequences like `\b` (at least the Unix conformant `echo`s).

Comment: @sch Are you sure? The `find` manpage shows `find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;` in the `EXAMPLES` section. Maybe some shells will treat braces specially.

Comment: Quotes don't harm but make no difference. All of `'{}'`, `\{\}`, `{}`, `"{}"`, `'{'}` are expanded by the shell (whatever Bourne-like shell) to one argument to find that is the two characters "{" and "}". Replace "find" with "echo find", or `printf '<%s>\n' find` if you want to double-check.

Comment: @QuasarDonkey See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which

Answer (score 2):

Better answers have already been given.

But note that spaces are not the only problem in the code you gave. tab, newline and wildcard characters are also a problem.

With

```
IFS='
'
set -f
for i in $(find . -name '*.jpg'); do echo "$i"; done
```

Then only newline characters are a problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you have mentioned is one of the basic problems that people face, when they try to read file names. Sometimes, people with limited knowledge  and having a misconception of file and folder structure tend to forget that "**In UNIX Everything is a file**" . So they don't understand that they need to handle spaces as well, as the file name can consist of 2 or more words with spaces.

**Solution :** So one of the better known ways of doing this is to do a **clean read** .

We here will read all the files present and keep them in a variable, next time when doing the desired processing we just will have to keep that variable inside quotes which will preserve the file names with spaces. This is one of the basic ways of doing it, however, the other answers provided by the other people here work just as well.

**SCRIPT :**

```
 find /path/to/files/ -iname "*jpg" | \
  while read I; do
   cp -v --parent "$I" /backup/dir/
  done
```

Here i am reading the files by giving the path to them and whatever i am reading i am keeping them inside a variable I, which i will quote at a later point while processing it to preserve the spaces so as to process it correctly.

Hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: "everything is a file" refers to something else. Your solution is GUN specific and doesn't cope with backslash or newline characters in filenames. "while read" loops in shells (IMO) is often an indication of bad shell scripting practice.

Comment: @sch : huh, and i used to think, it's ok. Thanks for pointing that out.I probably need to look at it more .

Comment: sorry,  I meant "GNU", not "GUN" above (it's the first time I realise those are anagrams BTW...)

Answer (score 1):

Simply with `find` and `bash` :

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec bash -c '
    echo "treating file $1 in bash, from path : ${1%/*}" 
' -- {} \;
```

This way, we use `$1` in bash, like in a basic script, that open nice perspectives to performs any advanced (or not) tasks.

A more efficient way (to avoid having to start a new bash for every file):

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'for i do
    echo "treating file $i in bash, from path : ${i%/*}" 
  done' -- {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent version of bash, you can use the `globstar` option:

```sh
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.jpg ; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

For simple actions, you can even skip the loop entirely:

```sh
echo **/*.jpg
```

Comment: While that works in zsh (where the feature originated from) and with ksh93 (with `set -G`), it shouldn't be used in bash as bash version is fundamentally broken (just like GNU `grep -r`) as it descends into symlinks to directories (equivalent to `find -L` or zsh's `***/*.jpg`). Also note that contrary to find, it will ommit dotfiles and not descend into dotdirs (by default).