# Cli grep through djvu files

Tags: djvu

How can I grep through djvu files? They are text files with some images in it. Is there some equivalent to `pdfgrep` tool?

Comment: Maybe there is some better utility for this, but [`djvutxt`](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/djvutxt.html) extracts the text layer (if there is one) and you can pipe that to `grep`.

Comment: Technically, if they contain images they are *not* text files.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `djvutxt` and then I use below script to search. I'm sure it can be improved. I tried a lot of `find` with `exec` and `xarg` commands with better or worse results. This seems to be working best for me.

```
 find . -iname "*djvu" | \
  while read I; do
   echo "$I"
   djvutxt "$I" | grep -i $1
  done
```

save as `grepdjvu.sh` and run as `bash grepdjvu.sh text_to_find`.

I copied this script from here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50319/322998 and modified.