# Quoting curly braces in the shell

Tags: shell, find, brace-expansion

I found examples of different quoting for curly braces for `find`, but I could not find an explanation. The possible choices are:
    1. `{}`
    2. `'{}'`
    3. `"{}"`
And they all seem to work fine. Is there a difference between them?

Comment: A duplicate as noted, but this page is nice and simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quoting would only be required if `{}` was interpreted by the shell. No modern shell (that I am aware of) interprets `{}` any way other than literally. In `bash` and `ksh93`, `{}` indicates a brace expansion, but since `{}` is an empty brace expansion, it isn't interpreted. In POSIX shell, it has no meaning, and so is also literal. I am not aware of it having any special meaning in the original Bourne shell, either.

Most likely this quoting is just people being cautious, and assuming `{` or `}` (or the two combined) may be interpreted as metacharacters by certain shells. In practise, I can't think of any shells that assign special meaning to it.

Comment: [As far as we could determine, no Bourne-style shell ever expanded `{}`, but some old csh did.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which)