# Why pipe doesn't work with upower -e

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

I've just found this command:

```bsh
upower -e
```

that displays a list of files that can be used with `upower -i` to display plugged device status.

So my first try was using:

```
upower -e | xargs upower -i
```

but it doesn't work. So I've tried:

```
$ upower -e | xargs echo
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o001 /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
```

and it display all files in single line. So I've used:

```
$ upower -e | xargs -0 echo
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o001
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
```

it works but displays one empty line, but this doesn't work:

```
$ upower -e | xargs -0 upower -i
failed to set path: Object path invalid: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o001
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
```

Why `upower -e | xargs upower -i` doesn't work? I'm using Bash on Fedora.

Is there something I'm missing here?

**EDIT**:

This seems to work:

```
upower -e | xargs -I {} upower -i "{}"
```

But I'm wondering: why a quote is needed if the filename doesn't have spaces?

Comment: Possibly `upower -i` can only handle a single object path at a time? Try `upower -e | xargs -L 1 upower -i`

Comment: @steeldriver got an answer on Twitter from the original author that posted this command, and it shows `xargs -I {}` works, but the files don't have spaces, then why this is needed?

Comment: `-I` isn't really needed, but it implies `-L1` as a side effect - that's what's really making the difference here I think

Comment: ... because the LHS should be `upower -e` presumably? `upower -i` needs an input path

Comment: @steeldriver Yes it was my mistake that I've just noticed, I've deleted that from my edit and comment.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your help. if you want to add this as an answer you can. I'm not sure how much people look at answers and comments on Unix SE.

Comment: OK thanks - done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`upower -e` produces a newline-separated list of object paths.

When you used `upower -e | xargs upower -i`, the `xargs` command tokenized that on whitespace and passed all the paths to a single invocation of `upower -i`, which it was unable to handle.

You then tried `upower -e | xargs echo`, and noted that the output consisted of a single line - that's down to `echo` though, and does not tell you how the output of `upower -e` was delimited.

Next you tried `upower -e | xargs -0 echo`, which (since the output of `upower -e` is **not** null delimited) passed a single multi-line argument to `echo`, which happily printed it. Similarly `upower -e | xargs -0 upower -i` passed a single multi-line path to `upower -i`, which unsurprisingly barfed.

Finally you discovered `upower -e | xargs -I {} upower -i "{}"`. Since `-I` implies `-L`, this passed each *line* of the `upower -e` output to a separate invocation of `upower -i`. You could have achieved the same with

```
upower -e | xargs -L upower -i
```

Whitespace *within* the paths isn't a factor here, but if it was, you should tell xargs not only to read a single line per invocation, but also to tokenize it on newlines only:

```
upower -e | xargs -d '\n' -L upower -i
```

or equivalently

```
upower -e | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 upower -i
```

Quoting the replacement text `{}` probably isn't necessary either (regardless of whether the text itself contains whitespace) - see [Quoting curly braces in the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/quoting-curly-braces-in-the-shell) and the linked duplicate discussing the same issue in the context of `find -exec`

Comment: Didn't know about `xargs -d '\n'`, it will be useful, most of the time I process lines with `xargs`.