# How to delete files only, but keep the directory structure?

Tags: bash, bash-script

I would like to delete every file, but keep the folder structure. Is there a way?

NOTE: (I'm using GNU bash 4.1.5).

Comment: How exactly do you mean to "exclude"? Are you using a command of some sort? If so please update your question to include this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073969/copy-folder-structure-sans-files-from-one-location-to-another

Comment: I think you mean delete every file.

Comment: @slm I updated with the command I usually use to exclude files.

Comment: No you haven't :-) Or, if you did, you removed it again

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . ! -type d -exec rm '{}' \;
```

This will delete every single file, excluding directories, below the current working directory. Be extremely careful with this command.

If the version of `find` on your machine supports it, you can also use

```
find . ! -type d -delete
```

Comment: @slm: I'm not sure how portable that is. I've added it in as a secondary option. I just realized that my edit made my answer virtually identical to yours. Sorry about that; it was not my intent.

Comment: Does the '{}' guard against spaces in files? I see you using all the time and I don't think I'd ever seen it used before I saw you posting solutions with it.

Comment: From the GNU find manpage: *"Notice that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks to
       protect them from interpretation as shell script punctuation."* I'm not sure when it's necessary though. I mostly do it out of habit. The `find` command never sees the quotation marks. It just sees the `{}` marker as an argument.

Comment: I see it on the example, but the templates show this, "`-exec command {} +`" & this "`-exec command ;`". I've use the `\;` in the past just never the '{}'.

Comment: @slm: The templates also don't show the escaping of the semicolon, which is generally necessary when using a shell to execute `find`. I think the templates are meant to show which arguments the `find` command needs and don't worry about anything shell-related.

Comment: @slm: You could. `\{\}` is the same as `'{}'`.

Comment: Found this U&L Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which. Doesn't appear that the '{}' is really necessary anymore.

Comment: @slm: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind for the next time I post a solution that uses `find -exec`.

Comment: Just asking b/c I'm trying to learn myself, why did you use `! -type d` vs. `-type f`?

Comment: @slm: `-type f` only matches regular files. It doesn't match special files such as symlinks and named-pipes.

Comment: Great tip.  I wanted to _empty_ my directory tree.  It has some symbolic links pointing to other directories.  To keep directories and links to directories ... Use:  `find . ! -xtype  d -delete`.  Keeps symbolic links to things of type **d** (directory).

Comment: Great tip.  I wanted to _empty_ my directory tree.  It has some symbolic links pointing to other directories.  To keep directories and links to directories ... Use:  `find . ! -xtype  d -delete`.  Keeps symbolic links to things of type **d** (directory).

Answer (score 9):

You can use the command `find` to locate every file but maintain the directory structure:

```
$ find /some/dir -type f -exec rm {} +
```

Per this Unix & Linux Q&A titled: [gnu find and masking the {} for some shells - which?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which), escaping the `{}` with single ticks (`'`) doesn't appear to be necessary anymore with modern day shells such as Bash.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to delete every regular file in the current directory and subdirectories recursively:

```
zsh -c 'rm **/*(.)'
```

Only zsh has [globbing qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to match files by type. However, the `rm` command doesn't work on directories, so in bash, you can use

```
shopt -s globstar
rm **/*
```

This doesn't work for commands other than `rm` though. In general, you can use `find`:

```
find . -type f -delete
```

or if your `find` doesn't support `-delete`:

```
find . -type f -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score -2):

I had similar requirement to delete files from a path and its sub directories (filtering by time ) with out deleting the directory structure .

And i have used the below format which worked for me .

find /test123/home/test_file_hip/data/nfs  -mtime +6 -type f  -exec rm   {} \;

Syntex : find (path of file) -mtime (greater than or less than days) -type f -exec rm {} \;

-type : Mention the type of file "f" for "d" directory 
-exec : execute command 
rm : remove 
{}  : output of find command

Note : Do test it before using it . 
Please feel free to correct or update if i missed anything .

Comment: since this is an additional requirement that wasn't mentioned by the OP, and since the basic `find ... rm` structure has already been covered, I'm not sure this is a valuable contribution as a new Answer to this question.