# Openssl on files found with find unix command

Tags: find, openssl

I can find the files I'm looking for with something like this:

```
find . -name "*.mp3";
```

What I want is something like this:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -in path/to/file.mp3 
-out path/to/file.enc -pass pass:pass;
```

But I have no idea how to reference the files which are found with find in the -exec portion of the command.

Comment: Use `{}`.­­­­­­

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `{}` to reference to your file. Hence:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -in "{}" -out "{}".enc -pass pass:pass \;
```

Comment: For each output overwrite on the same file `path/to/file.enc`?  And you'll need escaping `{}` and `;`.

Comment: @yaegashi Corrected that.

Comment: @yaegash Neither quoting nor escaping `{}` is necessary.  Try this: `touch 'a b'; find . -name 'a b' -exec ls -l -- {} \;`.  Quoting is pointless anyway, since `"{}"` is expanded by the shell before `find` gets to see it.

Comment: @lcd047 Quoting is done in case the file names have spaces.

Comment: @shivams Quoting of `{}` is done automatically by `find` when building the command line for `-exec`.  Please try the test I mentioned above.

Comment: @lcd047 Oh. okay. Thanks for that. I didn't know that.

Comment: @lcd047 Thanks for pointing it out :) Good summary: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8647/116972