# how to delete all files with specific extension in specific named folders in large tree?

Tags: files, find

I have large tree, with many `pdf` files in it. I want to delete the `pdf` files in this tree, but only those `pdf` files in sub folders named `rules/` There are other type of files inside `rules/`. The `rules/` subfolders have no other subfolders.

For example, I have this tree. Everything below 'source'

```
  source/
         A/
            rules/*.pdf, *.txt, *.c,etc..
            etc/
         B/
            keep_this.pdf                
            rules/*.pdf
            whatever/
         C/ 
            D/
               rules/*.pdf
               something/
```

and so on. There are `pdf` files all over the place, but I only want to delete all the `pdf` files which are in folders called `rules/` and no other place.

I think I need to use

```
  cd source
  find  / -type d -name "rules"  -print0 | xargs -0 <<<rm *.pdf?? now what?>>>
```

But I am not sure what to do after getting list of all subfolders named `rules/`

Any help is appreciated.

On Linux mint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would execute a `find` inside another `find`. For example, I would execute this command line in order to list the files that would be removed:

```
$ find /path/to/source -type d -name 'rules' -exec find '{}' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print ';'
```

Then, after checking the list, I would execute:

```
$ find /path/to/source -type d -name 'rules' -exec find '{}' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print -delete ';'
```

Answer (score 5):

With a shell that supports extended globs and null globs e.g. `zsh`:

```
for d in ./**/rules/
do
set -- ${d}*.pdf(N)                               
(( $# > 0 )) && printf %s\\n $@
done
```

or `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for d in ./**/rules/
do
set -- "${d}"*.pdf
(( $# > 0 )) && printf %s\\n "$@"
done
```

replace `printf %s\\n` with `rm` if you're happy with the result.

---

Since you are on gnu/linux you could also run:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*/rules/[^/]*.pdf' -delete
```

remove `-delete` if you want to perform a dry-run.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be

```
find source -name '*.pdf' -path '*/rules/*.pdf' -exec rm '{}' +
```

Why the first `-name`? Because it'll be a bit faster this way. Also `+` instead of `;` executes one `rm` with many arguments instead of many with one argument. So less process spawning. In bash you can get away without quoting `{}`.

Comment: Yes, I had this in mind but I avoided using it due to the initial requirements. Question was edited and this works now because _"the `rules/` subfolders have no other subfolders."_ otherwise with subdirs, a file like `./somedir/rules/noway/somefile.pdf` would be deleted even if it's not in `rules` but in one of its children so in that case prolly something like `find . -path '*/rules/*/*' -prune -o -path '*/rules/*.pdf' -delete` Anyway, you get my vote. As to _in bash you can get away without quoting {}_  - only a couple of shells [need that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8647)

Comment: Why -exec rm with all the parsing pitfalls and race conditions waiting to happen instead of -delete?

Comment: @Caleb - would you mind elaborating a bit on the first part ? What "parsing pitfalls" are we talking about when using `find` with `-exec rm {}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the current author of *rawhide* (*rh*) program that is used in this answer (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide):

```
rh -UUU '"*/rules/*.pdf".path'
```

The `'"*/rules/*.pdf".path'` argument searches for pdf files inside/under directories named "rules".

The `-UUU` argument unlinks/deletes/removes the matching files.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a bash script to do it (not the best way):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Don't screw us up with spaces!
IFS=$'\n'; set -f

DIRS=$(find . -type d -name "rules")

for i in $DIRS; do
  set +f
  rm $i/*.pdf
done
set +f
```

This iterates through the directories you find in your `find` command and removes the pdf's under each directory.

The line `IFS=$'\n'` is to cope with spaces in file names, and `set -f` is to cope with wildcard characters.
Of course, this is assuming you don't have newlines in any of your filenames.  If you do, the solution will become a lot more complicated.

Comment: What if any of those dirs has funky chars in its name (path) ? (hint: IFS)

Comment: @don_crissti The script would fail.  Don't put funky chars in your filenames, children! Although, any whitespace would also fail the script. That's a good point.

Comment: That's still pretty bad. Avoid the `for f in $(find...)` construct. `find` is a robust tool and you can do this `find`-only in a reliable manner.

Comment: Better than fiddling with IFS, you should just avoid the split+glob operator. There are robust ways to do it, why insist on fragile ways?

Comment: It's just one way to do it.  There are other ways that I haven't done before.  In fact, this is the way I would have done it before I learned about these things in find.

Comment: Have `find` execute your shell code e.g. `find . -type d -name rules -exec sh -c 'set -- "$0"/*.pdf; printf %s\\n "$@"' {} \;` (here instead of removing it prints the names of pdf's if any) that way it will always work with any kind of file names.