# find -exec not working in fish

Tags: find, fish

While using fish as my shell, i'm trying to set permissions on a bunch of c source files in current dir with

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec chmod 644 {} +;
```

I get an error

> find: missing argument to `-exec'

or

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I get an error

> chmod: cannot access '': No such file or directory

What's wrong?

Comment: try quoting the `{}` with `"{}"` or `'{}'` i.e. `find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec chmod 644 '{}' +`

Comment: why the `;` after `+` ?

Comment: @Anthon, if you only just arrived at this question, originally the OP posted the question without the `;`, ie. `.... chmod 644 {} +` . Then Thomas Dickey posted his answer, then the OP edited to add the `;` as you see it now. I know that still doesn't explain properly why the OP did it though...

Comment: @the_velour_fog I reviewed the question from the first post queue, you don't see the answers there. The `+;` looks someone mixed up things from find's man page.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the first command is just unnecessary but doesn't matter, both `bash` and `fish` eat it before passing the arguments to `find`

Comment: @ilkkachu Confirmed. Semicolon is redundant.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`fish` happens to be [one of the few shells where that `{}` needs to be quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247786/22565).

So, with that shell, you need:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec chmod 644 '{}' +
```

When not quoted, `{}` expands to an empty argument, so the command becomes the same as:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec chmod 644 '' +
```

And `find` complains about the missing `{}` (or `;` as `+` is only recognised as the `-exec` terminator when following `{}`).

With most other shells, you don't need the quotes around `{}`.

Comment: @Rahul Agreed. Can I change it to this answer?

Comment: I found this same trouble after much time trying to deal with git stashes O_o

Answer (score 3):

Your examples miss the expected trailing semicolon:

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

After revising the question, it is "fish" shell.  This is a known issue which can be worked around using quoting as @rahul noticed.  However, the escaping suggested does not work for my configuration: single quoting does:

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec chmod 644 '{}' \;
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec chmod 644 '{}' +
```

What *does* happen (if one types the characters rather than cut/paste) is that on trying to edit the command-line to escape the curly braces, *fish* gets confused and cannot proceed.  Here's a screenshot just after inserting the backslashes (no point in trying to cut/paste *that*):

[image: editing the command-line]

and then pressing return:

[image: just press return]

So ***no***, fish doesn't really work with escaped curly braces.  It only pretends to do that.  Continuing to press <kbd>enter</kbd> gives a conclusive demo:

[image: q.e.d.]

Further reading:

- [-exec not working in find #95](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/95)
- [Shell programming: How to use find in fish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392245/shell-programming-how-to-use-find-in-fish)

Comment: but the what is wrong with the first expression ?

Comment: I don't get an error with that.  OP may be confused with the latter.

Comment: With the above example I get chmod: cannot access '': No such file or directory

Comment: I am using fish shell.

Comment: Looks like `fish` is pre-interpreting the find command (and only knows about the second case).  I'll take a quick look for source to clarify this.

Comment: backslash-escaping the braces works fine in fish (v. 1.23.1, from Debian) _if_ you enter the characters from left to right, that is backslash-brace-backslash-brace. Entering the braces first and going back to enter the backslashes doesn't, since fish seems to consider the backslash as quoting the next character entered (like ^V in bash), not as a simple character. So, backslash-enter adds a newline to the command line, instead of submitting the command line to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

`{` and `}` have special meanings in fish. They need to be escaped in order to work with `find`, for example:

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec chmod 644 \{\} \;
```

Or you would have to quote `{}` like,

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec chmod 644 '{}' \;
```

Comment: I tried escaping for the "+" and it didn't work (perhaps version-dependent).  The single quotes work.

Comment: @ThomasDickey find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec chmod 644 \{\} +; seems to work as well in fish.

Comment: It only works if you cut/paste.  If you attempt to edit the line, it gets confused and breaks badly.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I am completely agree with you. I haven't tried the command before posting it.